# How to add signal method for my view?

Tags: django

I want to count how may files the user has uploaded.
I have added signals.py

```
from django.dispatch import Signal

upload_completed = Signal(providing_args=['upload'])
```

And summary.py

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .signals import upload_completed

@receiver(charge_completed)
    def increment_total_uploads(sender, total, **kwargs):
        total_u += total
```

to my project.

My views upload

```
@login_required
def upload(request):
    # Handle file upload
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.uploaded_by = request.user.profile
            upload_completed.send(sender=self.__class__, 'upload')
            #send signal to summary
            newdoc.save()
            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('upload'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the upload page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render(request,'upload.html',{'documents': documents, 'form': form})
```

This effort does not work.I got

```
    upload_completed.send(sender=self.__class__, 'upload')
                                                ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

I found signal example [testing-django-signals](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-testing-django-signals-like-a-pro-c7ed74279311)

```
from .signals import charge_completed
@classmethod
def process_charge(cls, total):
    # Process charge…
    if success:
        charge_completed.send_robust(
            sender=cls,
            total=total,
        )
```

But it seems to me that classmethod would not work in my case

How to fix my method?

Comment: What is that `'upload'` parameter for? As the error says, this is a basic Python syntax error and nothing to do with signals. Note however that your signal can't work as it doesn't define `total_u` and doesn't do anything to save the result anywhere anyway. Are you sure a signal is the right approach here?

Comment: I do not know,my idea is to count file uploads per user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the 'uploads' argument for the send() method.

But a tip, if you're planning on a persistent count of the number of file uploads (which I assume you most likely are), then I think you should create a new model so that you can save it in your database.Then you can update that model every time a Document model is saved.

And I suggest you have a look at [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save). Have a nice day coding!